# How to test the complete HTTP_REFERER string in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-referer

I would like to test the complete HTTP_REFERER string in htaccess but apparently it is not available.

I have a first site `https://firstdomain.org` and a second site `https://seconddomain.org`

In the first site there is link to `https://seconddomain.org`

I would like the second site to be opened only from this link in the first site (as far as possible).

When the second site is called from the link the value of `$_SERVER('HTTP_REFERER']` is something like this:
`https://firstdomain.org/index.php?r=something&cguid=7c6412345-8328-45b5-82c3-eb4c4596fe03`

I had in mind to test {HTTP_REFERER} in htaccess, but  as far as I can see the string
`?r=something&cguid=7c6412345-8328-45b5-82c3-eb4c4596fe03` is not available in htaccess {HTTP_REFERER}.

`RewriteRule %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://firstdomain.org/index.php` **It works**

`RewriteRule %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://firstdomain.org/index.php?r=something&cguid=7c6412345-8328-45b5-82c3-eb4c4596fe03` **It doesn't work**

Please, is there a way to get this string in htaccess?

Notice: I know that testing HTTP_REFERER is not 100% proof but with help of `cguid=7c6412345-8328-45b5-82c3-eb4c4596fe03` it should be enough for our needs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Oups!**

The issue was coming from the question mark in the string, the following will work:

```
RewriteRule %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://firstdomain.org/index.php?r=something&cguid=7c6412345-8328-45b5-82c3-eb4c4596fe03 **It doesn't work**

RewriteRule %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://firstdomain.org/index.php\\?r=something&cguid=7c6412345-8328-45b5-82c3-eb4c4596fe03 **It works**
```